# Getting application crash when retrieving latitude and longitude

Tags: android, gps, location, latitude-longitude

Hello i am currently trying to retrieve my current latitude and longitude and convert them into address, but i'm getting an application crash, everytime i run the program. Any idea what may be causing this?

Activity:

```
public class LocatahActivity extends Activity {

    LocationManager lm;
    String towers;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        towers = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);        

        //double lat = (location.getLatitude()*1E6);
        //double longi = (location.getLongitude()*1E6);

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double longi = location.getLongitude();

        Log.e("TAG", "Latitude: " + lat);
        Log.e("TAG", "Longitude: " + longi);

        TextView myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
        TextView myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
        TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

        myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(lat));
        myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(longi));

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, longi, 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getCountryName());

            myAddress.setText(sb.toString());
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            myAddress.setText("Cannont get Address!");
        }

    }


}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Logcat

```
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.location/com.example.location.LocatahActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at com.example.location.LocatahActivity.onCreate(LocatahActivity.java:44)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
08-01 19:20:45.572: E/AndroidRuntime(6233):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you provide a logcat also?

Comment: oops, sorry forgotten about the logcat, already updated the post

Comment: no such way exist. an inefficient way is to analyse possibility of null reference by yourself, make appropriate changes and run again . btw what is exact reason of not going through logcat ?

Comment: i already went through logcat and i know there's a null pointer exception but i can't figure out what it is and that's why im asking here?

Comment: double lat = location.getLatitude();

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `location` object is null. This is probably happening as you are using [getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29). You will get a null with this method if there is no last location, or if the provider is currently disabled.

Other than that, you say you want the current location. This is the wrong way to get the current location. To get the user's current location, you need to use the requestLocationUpdates() methods given in the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) API. Use those and a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) to receive updates. Keep in mind that it can take anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes before you get a location.